# Win 10 Login Accounts Without Password

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, login

So I upgraded my parents computer to Win 10 which went well, however I want both accounts to **not** have passwords, and just boot to a account selection screen so they can just select which one they want to log in. In trying to set this up I've had a few problems:

1. Using netplwiz if I check "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer", Windows automatically logs in to one of the accounts which is not what I want and doesn't seem to do what you'd think it does. None of the accounts have a password in the user account settings.
2. In netplwiz, if I uncheck "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer" it then asks me which user I want to automatcally log in. Removing a username from this entry field then causes windows to boot up and request login information for "Other User". I have no idea where this "Other user" account comes from as there's no "Other user in the Account Settings, or in the registry (under ProfileList). This is close to what I want but the "Other user" entry is annoying, especially as it requires a input before getting to a screen where the "real" accounts can be selected.

Shown automatically at start up:
[image]

Clicking ok then takes to this screen with other "real" user accounts are available for in bottom left corner:
[image]

I'm starting to think it's not actually possible to do what I'm trying to do, although I find it hard to believe as it seems like something a lot of people would want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve what you originally wanted, all you had to do is to remove passwords from both user accounts (i.e. specify an empty password for each). That way, if you have more than one interactive user registered on the computer, Windows will boot to the welcome screen giving you a list of users and the opportunity to log into any of these accounts simply by clicking a "Sign In" button (no password to enter).

And there's no need to fiddle with `netplwiz` for that. The  "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer" box should remain checked.

Whatever you are experiencing must be a consequence of some peculiar set of changes you made through `netplwiz`. I suggest you revert it to the way it was originally and simply specify an empty password for each account.