# How to run a unity-built after Computer is turned on

Tags: windows-10, powershell, task-scheduler, kiosk, unity3d

**Goal**

- User turns on Computer and Unity-built runs automatically.
- Upon system start and thereafter Unity start, User only sees the maximized ***gameview*** of unity. No windows Taskbar, steamVR window, nor anything else is visible.
- Unity-built quits and computer shuts down automatically upon respective user-input within the running Unity application.

The following approach is my current plan. Simpler solutions are always welcome.

I've tried Windows Kiosk Mode, but manual login to kiosk account was still necessary. Plus Unity doesn't seem to be available in Kiosk mode - or I overlooked something...

**Step by step:**

1. User turns on computer by pressing the power-button.
2. User-Login happens automatically; no user-input necessary (neither click, nor password input).
3. if a password protected account exists; login happens automatically.
4. if user-account exists, but without password protection; login happens automatically
5. Unity-built starts immediately.
6. Screen only shows game content; neither windows start menu, nor anything else is shown on the screen.
7. User has in-game options (within the running Unity application) to quit the game. Both Unity application and system shut down after user picks respective option.

### Step 1 - 5:

I've been able to start the unity-built after system start via ***task scheduler***, but I couldn't solve the problem of automatically logging into the user-account.

- `Edit 1:`
  I mangaged to disable required account-password input. User now reaches the desktop without having to input anything. I used `strg + r and "netplwiz"` which is described in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1003749/win-10-login-accounts-without-password?rq=1).

### Step 6:

**Problem**: After unity start Windows start menu and steamVR windows are visible and overlay the gameview. User has to click into the gameview, to "pull" gameview to the front in order to hide said overlaying elements.

**Solution**: ???

Comment: Josh - Is the account you want to auto login a local account on the Windows 10 machine? You only need help now getting it to login automatically with a password, right? I know how you can do this if this is a hurdle you need help with. It sounds like getting the Unity to start up and take over screen is resolved as well as the shutdown requirements you mention so one thing at a time.... you only need help with the automatic login of the local computer account (not a domain account), right?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for your help. As stated in "**Edit 1**" I have already successfully managed to bypass the login. Unity then runs automatically and shows the maximized game view. Unfortunately despite the maximized gameview, a little steamVR window is still shown and the taskbar is also visible and both shouldn't be visible. Getting those details to stay hidden is the next problem. Imagine you start your Playstaytion. After pressing the power button you only see what you're supposed to see. I want to the same with this computer + unity.